# Многомерные массивы python

Tags: python

Как написать функцию которая генерируют **Многомерный массив** изходя из входных данных.

```
например входит число N, то результатом будет массив N на N
```

Comment: Может Вас устроит такой вариант?  

    def getArray(n):
        res= []
        for i in xrange(n): res+=[[0]*n]
        return res
    print getArray(n)[0][0]
А вообще, как сказано ниже, нет встроенных многомерных массивов в языке. Есть list, tuple, dictionary.

Comment: Ну многомерных массивов нет, а транспонирование матрицы в cеми байтах от Норвига есть. http://www.norvig.com/python-iaq.html

Comment: А еще можно сделать `dict` `tuple`'ов длиной 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если нужны именно массивы [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) или `bytearray`, то никак. В Python нет многомерных массивов.

Разве что сделать одномерный массив размером `n*n`, и обращаться по индексу `x+n*y`. Например, как `bytearray(n*n)` или, скажем, `array.array("l", [0 for _ in range(0, n*n)])`.

Если под понятие «многомерного массива» подойдет понятие «списка списков» (списки в CPython реализованы именно как [массивы](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), то, собственно, сделать их. Например, так:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> [[0 for _ in range(0, n)] for _ in range(0, n)]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Если нужны именно матрицы, то можно воспользоваться [NumPy](https://numpy.org/):

```
>>> numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros((n, n)))
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Или, если нужны не матрицы (а n×n было частным случаем), то, непосредственно, `numpy.array`:

```
>>> numpy.zeros((n, n))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Или, как верно замечает @mikillskegg, например, если требуется массив не чисел, то вместо `numpy.array`/`numpy.zeros` можно воспользоваться более низкоуровневым интерфейсом [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.ndarray(shape=(n, n), dtype=(unicode, 1))
>>> a.fill(u"X")
array([[u'X', u'X', u'X'],
       [u'X', u'X', u'X'],
       [u'X', u'X', u'X']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Вообще, вопрос странно сформулирован, т.к. ни слова не сказано ни про данные, которые должны храниться в структуре, ни про свойства, которыми структура должна обладать.

Comment: Про numpy.ndarray забыли?

Comment: @mikillskegg, так ведь `numpy.zeros` это оно и есть. [Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty`.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)

Comment: А если нужен массив не числовых данных, а чего-то другого? zero - лишь очень частное удобство. И уж спрашивающему нужно указать на основной контейнер, а не на частный случай.

Comment: Согласен, справедливое замечание. Отредактирвал, дополнил.