# Создание n-мерного массива длины n

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, python-3.x

Можно ли создать `n`-мерный массив? Если да то как это реализовать? Если матрица это "список списков", то он будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
[  [ [...[]...] ],[ [...[]...] ]  ]
```

Ну, или чтоб понятней былo, как `n` вложенных отрезков,картинка ниже,

```
(a1[...[]...]b1, a2_m[...[]...]b2_m,...)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как это в коде реализовать? Если скажем,мне нужно вводить `n` с клавиатуры. Большое спасибо!

[Вот вопрос по многомерным массивам,который не подошел мне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/158145/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробовал воспользоваться рекурсией.
Первый аргумент - глубина массива.
Второй аргумент - количество элементов в массиве.

```
def quant_array(n, x):
    try:
        assert isinstance(n, int)
    except AssertionError:
        return "Input an integer!"
    if n <= 1:
        return [n]*x
    return [(n, quant_array(n-1, x))]*x


print(quant_array(3, 2))
```

> [(3, [(2, [1, 1]), (2, [1, 1])]), (3, [(2, [1, 1]), (2, [1, 1])])]

Comment: Спасибо, а как его, заполнить, к примеру, нулями?

Comment: Обновил код, может наведет на мысль.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы создать `n`-мерный `numpy` массив, у которого каждое измерение имеет `n` элементов:

```
>>> import numpy as np  # $ pip install numpy 
>>> n = 3 
>>> np.arange(n**n).reshape(*[n]*n)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы всего `n` элементов было:

```
>>> np.arange(n).reshape(n, *[1]*(n-1))
array([[[0]],

       [[1]],

       [[2]]])
```

Comment: а зачем звездочка в начале: `*[n]*n` ? `reshape([n]*n)` - тоже должен работать

Comment: @MaxU да, первый пример работает со звёздочкой и без. Во втором звёздочка не опциональна. Я начал  редактировать с [примера с несколькими аргументами](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39069988/4279) (по документации, я не вижу вообще поддержки этого случая).

Comment: вот альтернативный вариант: `np.arange(n).reshape((n,) + tuple([1]*(n-1)))`

Comment: @MaxU  `[n]+[1]*(n-1)` также работает. Можно и так и так, главное не смешивать `reshape((n, m))` и reshape(n, m)` (без лишних скобок слегка красивее, но это дело вкуса).